# Modify specific line in a yaml file using bash

Tags: bash

I am trying to make `sed` to modify a content of yaml file which is as follows:

```
image-1:
    PrName: client Image
    number: client-image-1
    path: /home/user/
    name: client-image
    tag: 0.0.1-5

image-2:
    PrName: Server Image
    number: Server-image-1
    path: /home/user/
    name: server-image
    tag: 1.0.1-3
```

I want to have sed function to modify the content of yaml file. It modifies the tag of image-2 with specific value `$NEW_TAG` which is given as env variable.

I started with but I don't think it'd help
`"sed -i 's#tag:*?#$NEW_TAG?#' file.yaml"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a proper yaml parser like [yq](https://github.com/mikefarah/yq/):

```bash
$ NEW_TAG=1.0.2 yq e --inplace ".image-2.tag|=strenv(NEW_TAG)" file.yaml
$ cat file.yaml
image-1:
  PrName: client Image
  number: client-image-1
  path: /home/user/
  name: client-image
  tag: 0.0.1-5
image-2:
  PrName: Server Image
  number: Server-image-1
  path: /home/user/
  name: server-image
  tag: 1.0.2
```

Comment: But this one will create another line and does not modify the content of the yaml file.

Answer (score 1):

Solutions using text processors like `sed` can easily fail if the document's representation changes. The [YAML specs](https://yaml.org/spec/1.2.2/) offer more freedom in this regard (indentation, ordering, escaping, etc. while not modifying the logical content of the document) than text processors can natively handle.

Better use YAML processors instead that can abstract from the actual representation. Here are some suggestions:

- mikefarah/yq: https://github.com/mikefarah/yq

```bash
NEW_TAG=1.2.3-4
tag="$NEW_TAG" yq '.image-2.tag = strenv(tag)'
```

- kislyuk/yq: https://github.com/kislyuk/yq

```bash
NEW_TAG=1.2.3-4
yq -y --arg tag "$NEW_TAG" '."image-2".tag = $tag'
```

- itchyny/gojq: https://github.com/itchyny/gojq

```bash
NEW_TAG=1.2.3-4
gojq --yaml-input --yaml-output --arg tag "$NEW_TAG" '."image-2".tag = $tag'
```

Output:

```yaml
image-1:
  PrName: client Image
  number: client-image-1
  path: /home/user/
  name: client-image
  tag: 0.0.1-5
image-2:
  PrName: Server Image
  number: Server-image-1
  path: /home/user/
  name: server-image
  tag: 1.2.3-4
```